# Google dialogflow - Unable to place call on the number obtained from DialogFlow Phone Gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

I am building a voice-2-voice demo and am using DialogFlow Phone Gateway to dial calls using Skype. Previously, I was able to place calls using Skype, but now I am unable to do so as the number is unavailable, since i changed the agent id and phone number to change the voice model for this demo.

I have tried other alternatives, but this number is still unavailable. Can someone please help me with this? I have attached screens for it as well.

*Corrected URL in the snapshot: https://www.app.resemble.ai/api/v2/integrations/dialogflow*

[image: enter image denter image description hereescription here]

It was executing before, but now it is not working.[image]

Comment: Hi @zybe, Can you check this [link1](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/phone-gateway?hl=en#limit) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-settings?hl=en#change-editions) ? Let me know if this helps you or not.